# WPF overlay control

Tags: wpf, windows, user-controls

thanks for the all the help in past questions. I have come to summon you once again.

So let's say I have same size user controls A,B with a z-index of 0,1, respectably.

Is it possible to have B not catch any touches that are intended to A?

Basically I would like to have a user control which comes up over another but does not block touches.

Thanks,

Comment: Let's say user control A is a rectangle with a fill and B a textblock of the same size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the [UIElement.IsHitTestVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible.aspx) property to `false`, your control should not "catch any touches".  For details, refer to [Hit Testing Support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097.aspx).

Comment: Interesting, I will try that. Thanks you.

Comment: Will this inform you about hit tests on visuals which are overlapped by the control which has set the property to false? I suspect it might not but ofcourse I could be wrong.

Comment: @TejasSharma It will just cause that control (and its children) to be ignored completely by the hit testing system.  In this case, control `B` will just be bypassed, so `A` will receive all hits, which is what the OP wanted.

Comment: ah okay, would not have thought that!

Comment: Once again, I would like to thank Reed for his help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hit testing to inform you about ALL visuals at a location, not just the topmost one by using the `HitTestResultCallback`. This is how you use it: http://hintdesk.com/c-wpf-hit-testing-example/